# Killing external process inside background worker

Tags: c#, process, backgroundworker

I'm having this code inside a DoWork of a background worker:

```
Process downloadConvert = new Process();
downloadConvert.StartInfo.FileName = @"process.exe";
downloadConvert.StartInfo.Arguments = "args here";
downloadConvert.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
downloadConvert.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
downloadConvert.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
downloadConvert.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
downloadConvert.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
downloadConvert.OutputDataReceived += (s, er) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(er.Data);
    if (er.Data != null && er.Data != "")
    {
        metadata trackInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<metadata>(er.Data);
        title.Add(trackInfo.title);
    }

    if (fetchInfoBW.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        downloadConvert.Kill();
        downloadConvert.WaitForExit();
        return;
    }
};

downloadConvert.Start();
downloadConvert.BeginOutputReadLine();
downloadConvert.WaitForExit();
```

I've added cancellation support to my worker and I want it to exit after I press a button. Since the worker is actually the process itself and the process keeps sending output while active, I'm trying to find a way to terminate/kill/stop it from the OutputDataReceived. The code above seems to successfully kill the process(it no longer sends debug output) but for some reason the worker's completed event is never fired and the application stops there.

Comment: Well actually this was more tha rediculous. Of course it worked. Instead of just running the CancelAsync on button press, I also killed the process itself. The worker_completed method fires normally now and I can display info using the e.Cancel.You can make an answer so I can upvote you. Thanks

Comment: You can actually self-answer your own question. Doing so is not out of the ordinary here on StackOverflow, and certainly not frowned upon either. So, answer away, if you like ;-) (FYI: The WaitForExit inside your OutputDataReceived handler is not only redundant, but also without purpose)

Comment: I will answer it thank you. About the WaitForExit, If I didn't put it there, I was getting an access denied error and the app was crashing. According to the Kill() documentation by MS, it is recommended to run a WaitForExit after the Kill() anyway

Comment: That's curious. You have WaitForExit already outside the handler (as part of the method your background worker thread is executing, i guess). Hmm, perhaps invoking Kill from within the handler leaves some handle/resource in an invalid state until the OS comes around to actuall killing and cleaning the process, making the Process class misbehave when the handler returns to the calling code within the Process class. TIL... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to declare the Process globally and then initialize it locally. That way it was visible in the whole application and I was able to kill it on button press while I was also calling the CancelAsync() method on the worker.